# C++/CLI generic functions not accessible from c# due to it's protection level

Tags: c#, generics, c++-cli

I have written a C++/CLI library that exports a class with two generic functions:

```
public ref class TargetInterface
{
public:
    static uint32_t buffer_length = 4096;
    TargetInterface();

    static bool Connect(char* deviceAdress);
    static void Disconnect(char* deviceAdress);

    generic<typename T>CommunicationState WriteProtobufMessage( T object);

    generic<typename T>CommunicationState ReadProtobufMessage([Out] T object);

};
```

The dll compiles fine. When I try to use this functions in my C# project I get the error:

```
WavelabsLightsourceSystem.TargetInterface.ReadProtobufMessage<T>(T)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Here is the c# part where I try to use the Funktions:

```
       pb_MessageHeader header = new pb_MessageHeader();
       TargetInterface target = new TargetInterface();

       target.ReadProtobufMessage<pb_MessageHeader>(header);
```

Comment: My crystal ball says: "You forgot to make CommunicationState public".

Answer (score 1):

As per Hans Passants comment I had to make the `CommunicationState` enum public.

Thanks Hans, your Crystall ball was correct. I didn't dream of, that I have to make an enum public.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same exact issue, but my problem was actually due to different .NET Frameworks being targeted in different projects, as detailed here:

[Why do I get a warning icon when I add a reference to an MEF plugin project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186216/why-do-i-get-a-warning-icon-when-i-add-a-reference-to-an-mef-plugin-project)