# Why do I get a warning icon when I add a reference to an MEF plugin project?

Tags: .net, mef, project-reference

I wish to test the core class of a plugin by directly referencing the plugin project and instantiating the plugin class. When I create a test Console App project and add a project reference to the plugin project, I get a warning icon (yellow triangle with exclamation mark) next to the reference in the References list.

When I instead add a reference to the dll, the assembly build output of the plugin, I get no such warning. What could this warning be trying to tell me?

Comment: Most of the time, warning triangles will have tool tips or (failing that) an entry in the errors window. At a guess, the two projects have incompatible dependencies.

Comment: Any warnings in the console when trying to build?

Answer (score 726, accepted):

As mentioned in the question's comments, differing .NET Framework versions between the projects can cause this. Check your new project's properties to ensure that a different default version isn't being used.

Comment: What I also need to know is why visual studio accepted adding those references then?

Comment: I'm using VS 2015 and the problem is still there. I've lost half an hour until I came here.

Comment: not even any hover text or build errors explaining what the issue is

Comment: Can confirm that this was the root of the issue. Can also confirm that Visual Studio 2017 with update 15.3 has still not addressed the issue of not actually showing a meaningful message. Very annoying.

Comment: @matao Agreed! Its annoying I couldn't get any details about the error...

Comment: @TsarBomba No it shouldn't be the accepted answer, because both projects in question for .Net Core 2.

Comment: It seems like very poor UI decision in VS to represent this only by an icon, considering all the things that could go wrong with a reference (file not found, wrong framework version, wrong platform, dependency issues, etc.) a tooltip or something would really help here.

Comment: I had to restart Visual Studio in order for the warning icons to go away after I fixed up the projects.

Comment: Still working through my issues with VS2019 here.  I have a working solution in devops.  If I connect to the remote repo and synch, I still have dependency issues.  Did a Nuget refresh - this has no effect.  Building a corporate database on time spent on issues that side-track developers (so that we can improve our estimates).  Git and devops issues are pretty much the main contributors.  In some cases this kind of issue takes more than four hours to resolve.

Comment: I'm curious as to why the VS team - after nearly a decade - still hasn't figured out that a warning icon could benefit from a tooltip.

Answer (score 79):

Encountered the same issue with a ASP.Net Web App and two library class projects which needed to be referenced within the Web App.  I had no information provided on why the build failed and the references were invalid.

Solution was to ensure all projects had the same Target Framework:

In Visual Studio 2015- **Right Click project > Properties > Application > Target Framework**

Save, Clean and Rebuild solution.  The project references should no longer appear as yellow warnings and the solution will compile.

My Web App was targeting .Net 4.5 whereas the other two dependent library class projects targeted .Net v4.5.2

Answer (score 51):

1. Make sure **all versions are same for each projects** click each projects and see the version here Project > Properties > Application > Target .NET framework
2. a. Go to Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Console Type **Update-Package -Reinstall** (if not working proceed to **2.b**)

   b. ***THIS IS CRITICAL BUT THE BIGGEST POSSIBILITY THAT WILL WORK***. **Remove < Target > *Maybe with multiple lines* < /Target >** usually found at the bottom part of .csproj.
3. Save, load and build the solution.

Comment: Thanks for that, a nice error message in Visual Studio about .Net versions wouldn't go astray here!

Comment: @colmde interestingly if you clean solution the output window displays the following message: 'Package was restored using .NetFramework XXX instead of target framework .NetFramework XXX. The package may not be fully compatible with your project'

Comment: Part 2.b which was not noted in other answers was critical for me! 2.b Remove < Target > Maybe with multiple lines < /Target > usually found at the bottom part of .csproj.

Comment: Part 2.b is completely insane but it works ! thanks

Comment: Thanks
2.b did the trick for me too.
Would NEVER have figured this out myself.

Comment: @shelbypereira I will update my answer, thanks for that

Comment: @Elo I'm glad it helped.

Comment: @HenrikClausen Nice to hear. Thank you.

Answer (score 47):

For both of (or all of) the projects that you want to use together:

Right click on the project > Properties > Application > Target .NET framework

Make sure that both of (or all of) your projects are using the same .NET framework version.

Comment: Perfect, worked for me! I had an MVC project with .NET Framework 4.5.2. And my class libraries that are referencing it were .NET Framework 4.7.

Comment: One would think that new projects added to an existing solution would be smart enough to know what version, but sadly not the case.

Answer (score 31):

Reinstall all packages in all projects of the current solution:

```
Update-Package -Reinstall
```

Comment: Although this suggestion did not directly resolve my issue, it pointed me in the right direction for my scenario. For those that it may help, I actually had to change my NuGet package source to v3 for Update-Package to find the right version to download: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-dialog#package-sources

Comment: It removed all packages, installed them and the yellow triangles came back.

Comment: Awesome helped me.

Answer (score 21):

Try closing and opening VS.

Seems silly but after 1 hour of following the above and finding everything lined up OK. I restarted VS 2017 and the problems were gone.

Comment: Worked for me.  Silly or not sometimes, Visual Studio gets confused and it's cache gets screwed up.  Thanks for suggesting it - hated to do it because I felt stupid thinking it would work but what the "heck" - after an hour of other things I might as well and tada it worked

Comment: VS 2019...same.  This answer should move to the top to simply save those of us fighting ghosts from wasting our time.

Comment: Before closing, you can simply select References in the solution explorer and click the refresh button. Work wonders for me.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you have the **projects targeting the same framework version**. Most of the times the reason would be that current project ( where you are adding reference of another project ) points to a **different .net framework version than the rest ones**.

Answer (score 8):

For me, I ran into this issue when referencing a .NET Standard 2.0 class library in a .NET Framework 4.7.1 console application. Yes, the frameworks are different, but they are compatible (.NET Standard is supposed to jive with both .NET Core and .NET Framework.) I tried cleaning, rebuilding, removing and readding the project reference, etc... with no success. Finally, quitting Visual Studio and reopening resolved the issue.

Comment: Similar situation! .NETCore 3.0 and .NETStandard 2.0 library, compiled recompiled, deleted and readded, no way until i restarted VS. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Check NETFramework of the referred dll & the Project where you are adding the DLL.
Ex: 
DLL     ==> supportedRuntime version="v4.0"
Project ==> supportedRuntime version="v3.0"

You will get  warning icon.
Solution : Make dll version consistence across.

Answer (score 5):

Using Visual Studio 2019 with all projects targeting .Net Core 3.1 the solution was to:

1. **Clean / Build / Rebuild.**
2. **Restart Visual Studio 2019**

Answer (score 4):

It's been a long time since this question was asked but if someone is still interested - I recently ran into similar icons. I was compiling a C#.net project using VS 2008. I found VS could not locate the assemblies for those references. When I double clicked VS refreshed the references and removed the icons on some of those[EDIT: which it could NOW locate]. For remaining references, I had to compile the respective assemblies.

Answer (score 4):

Adding my 2 cents to the @kad81 answer,

Go to Visual Studio -> BUILD -> Configuration Manager

In the "Active Solution Platform" drop down in top right hand corner (mine is VS 2012), if it is "Mixed Platforms", change it to the appropriate platform based upon your reference third party assemblies.

Then in each of the project in the list, make sure you select same platform for all the project. (if x86 not exist, then select "", then you can select "x86".)

Rebuild the library projects first and then referencing projects. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

In Asp.net core sometime it shows alert if you changes the project name space or name. To remove this kind of alerts you just Unload Project and load it again. 
If issue is still there means you it can not find your Assembly reference.

Answer (score 3):

Also happens if you explicitly reference a project that was already implicitly referenced.

i.e

- project a references project b
- project c references project a (which adds implicit ref. Expand and see)
- project c references project b

you will see an exclamation mark next to b under project references.

Comment: Or referencing both the project and the dll built by the project.

Answer (score 1):

I had these icons for a different reason. We have one big solution for all our projects (nearly 100). I made a subselection of the projects I was interested in and made a new solution. However the references where project references instead of references to the compiled dll's....

After some research I found [this link on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4358) which explains this is new behaviour in VS2015.

On the GitHub page they explain a workaround for converting project references to binary references.

Answer (score 1):

To fix some not working stuff it has sense *to remove* some libraries sometimes, how would not that sound weird.

Anyways, I believe *the problem is too wide* and might be caused *by different factors*, so want to share my situation/solution.

I had a project (brought by customer) with Xamarin Forms and Telerik libraries. The thing was in general related to the components, which **libraries are not included** into packages folder, nor available via Nuget (paid ones).

*The whole project References were "yellow", it looked horribly and scary.*

The **solution** was just **to remove** those Telerik **references** (including a few controls in code which were using that). Right after that all the references magically got their common normal grey color and the errors (mostly) disappeared.

"Mostly" - because "all red around" error messages about "the element is not defined anywhere" sometimes happen still. That's weird, and brings inconvenience, but I still able to compile and run the project(s): just need to clean solution, restart Visual Studio, pray a little bit, clean again, remove obj/bin folders, restart again, and it works well.

The key thing is **remove not available libraries references**, as the error messages say absolutely another stuff. (For instance, something like "Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinDownloadArchives not found or cannot find something" etc., but that just might mean you don't have some references available.

Then remove packages folder, reload/reopen the project/solution, go to "Manage Nuget Packages" and click "Restore" button.

Answer (score 1):

In a multi-project solution, If every other thing failed... On the startUp project, check.
Dependencies->Assemblies and see if the erring referenced project is there. Remove it and re-build.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in a solution with projects targting .NET Core 3.1, .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.8. The issue was on this last one.

The trick that solved the issue for me, was to change the target framework to .NET Framework 4.5, then back to .NET Framework 4.8.

I have absolutely no idea why this fixed the issue, but it did.

The IDE was Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: This worked in VS2022.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from @AljohnYamaro (sorry, couldn't comment on your answer, new account without enough reputation yet, but upvotaded you), I've checked the .csproj file.

On my file, besides the standard project reference:

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\ProjectA\ProjectA.csproj">
    <Private>true</Private>
    <CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies>true</CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies>
</ProjectReference>
```

There were also a directy link to the compiled *dll* from the referenced project:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="ProjectA">
    <HintPath>..\ProjectA\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\ProjectA.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Removing this second reference solved the issue.

Comment: Same problem occured in my solution. I had both ProjectReferences and References (DLL) in my .csproj file. It can happen if you resolve code problems with 'Add reference to DLL' option - it adds new Reference.

Answer (score 1):

Open the YOURPROJECT.csproj file with a text editor then at the end of the file remove these lines inside the target tag, and then build the project again!
be sure the Package folder is in the correct path which mentioned in **< Reference > < HintPath >**

```
<Error Condition="!Exists('.......
```

Enjoy it ;)

Answer (score 1):

one more simple answer : exit visual studio and re-open it, it has solved for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem but my case was a bit different the ones above. I tried to open a project created in a different computer. I found that the path to package folder is not updated when you add a reference so restarting VS, changing .NET version, or any mentioned recommendation does not solve the problem. I opened the csproj file in notepad++ and corrected all the relative paths to packages folder. Then; all the warnings are gone. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

in VS 2017 Do a Clean then Build

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help. Here is a breakdown of how I fixed my problem:

Right click on your project > Properties

Under Application change the target Framework. In my case ImageSharp was using .Net 4.6.1. You can find this in your packages.config.

Go to your project references. You'll notice SixLabors has a yellow triangle. You have to update the NuGet package.

Right click on References > Manage NuGet Packages.

Update SixLabors.

You might have slight code updates (see below) but this fixed my problem.

[Convert ImageSharp.Image to ImageSharp.PixelFormats.Rgba32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57789399/convert-imagesharp-image-to-imagesharp-pixelformats-rgba32)

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2019, one of my projects target framework was .net core but it was referencing another project whose target framework was .net standard. I changed all of the projects to reference .net standard and the icons went away. To see what your project is right click it and click properties and look at Target framework. You can also normal click the project itself and look at the < TargetFramework > tag under < PropertyGroup >

Answer (score 0):

I had created a new .sln which was put in a subfolder. The .nuget folder was missing from where that .sln file was added. Moving the .nuget folder from the root into the subfolder where my new .sln file was solved the issue for me.

I came back later and added the .sln file to the root and deleted the subfolder. Doing this originally would have solved the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons to get this annoying yellow triangle is that you are adding a reference to a project twice, meaning:

- Reference one: **MyProjectOne** (which contains already a reference to **MyProjectTwo**)
- Reference two: **MyProjectTwo**

By deleting the Reference two, the yellow triangle will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the newer style Sdk projects add OutputType to the ProjectGroup element with a value of Library in the project you're referencing.
It'll also give you grief if it's in the project you're referencing and it references a project without the setting.

Answer (score 0):

find your .csprojc file and open it.

find your packages path. I fixed my project by this issue.

```
..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll
```

this .. means vs will find this dll in parent directory.

you should confirm your package path, and your will fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but in my case the problem was next:

- I have a Main Project with some NuGet packages installed (one of them has a Common.dll assembly)
- I added a Class Library Project named Common to my Solution
- I added Project Reference between Main Project and Class Library Project
- I see the Yellow Triangle near my Reference
- When I start to build my Main Project I get an error

To fix this problem I have to rename my Common Project

Answer (score 0):

2024 and this happened to me, converting an old .Net Framework solution to .Net 8. The problem was in different $Configuration|$Platform combinations in all converted projects. I opened all the *.csproj files in np++ and deleted all conflicting configurations/platforms.