# How to use C# dll in F# project? Getting yellow triangle with an exclamation mark

Tags: c#, f#, project-reference

I need to maintain a F# project. Right now I need to import a C# dll and make use a function in there.

What I have done is that in the F# solution, I have added the C# project, then in the F# project, I have added this new C# project as a reference. The exact step is as follows.

in solution explorer, I have located the F# project.
right clicked references, and add reference.
Under solution category, I checked the C# project.

After all these steps. my C# project is listed as one of the references in the solution explorer. but it has a yellow triangle with an exclamation mark on it.

In the F# solution file.
I have tried the following

```
open CSV_Reader    //this is the project name, and also the namespace


module Stage =

    CSV_Reader.Parser.InsertIntoDB(connStr, tableName, csvFilePath)
```

the compiler is telling me for the 2 occurrences of CSV_Reader

```
The namespace or module 'CSV_Reader' is not defined
The namespace or module 'CSV_Reader' is not defined
```

EDIT:

Thanks to [the link (likely duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186216/why-do-i-get-a-warning-icon-when-i-add-a-reference-to-an-mef-plugin-project) provided by Guy Coder, tt turns out that the problem I am running into is a .net framework mismatch issue. The F# project runs on .net 4 but the C# dll is written in .net 4.5. Therefore when I make a reference to the C# project, there is a yellow triangle with exclamation mark. All i need to do is to modify the C# dll project to use the same version of .net framework as the F# project and the issue is resolved.

Comment: @Ian how do you add a dll to a F# project? I don't see a place to do that in Reference manager

Comment: I take it that you are trying to compile the project and not run it from F# Interactive? I ask because the link above is about using F# Interactive.

Comment: @GuyCoder you are correct. and I have tried the link above before openning this thread

Comment: This might help: [Why do I get a warning icon when I add a reference to an MEF plugin project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186216/why-do-i-get-a-warning-icon-when-i-add-a-reference-to-an-mef-plugin-project) It might be different versions of .NET for the C# and F# projects.

Comment: @GuyCoder hi, yes that link you provided does solve part of my problem. It is indeed a .net framework mismatch problem.