# The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net' (are you missing an assembly reference?) only onruntime

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

this error apears only on run time not on build the build success
[image]

[image]

what is the yellow mark beside the reference mean

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this myself (the yellow), but no problem really occurred during execution. Anyways I have found some references of your problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186216/why-do-i-get-a-warning-icon-when-i-add-a-reference-to-an-mef-plugin-project). The second most voted answer that includes Save, Clean and Rebuild solution seems appropriate.

Hope this helps you with your problem.