# Error when exporting data to excel in c# (win forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, file, datagridview

When trying to export data from `DataGridView` to excel `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.'` exception is thrown, funny thing is that file is saved like supposed to.
I fought that this is because I [reinstalled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33300344/7517846) packages for entire solution, but it's not the case.

Exception occurs when trying to call [`Process.Start(fileName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca(v=vs.110).aspx) method, where the value of fileName is: `C:\\Users\\net\\Desktop\\Excel TESTING\\OperatorStatisticsData.xlsx`

Note that my application is running on any CPU( 32 or 64 bit), and I am currently running win10 64 bit operating system. 
[image]
Any suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: @mjwills my apologies, there are too many methods, i fought the information about reinstalling packages would be enough, check out my [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48005685/7517846) question

Comment: @mjwills `"C:\\Users\\net\\Desktop\\Excel TESTING\\OperatorStatisticsData.xlsx"`  no need for downvote

Comment: @mjwills tried it, still  same, but funny thing as i mentioned is that data is saved like supposed to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call `EXCEL.EXE` directly (change path if need to):

```
string filePath = @"c:\Temp\export.XLSX";
// For me this generates: C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\EXCEL.EXE
var exec = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramW6432"),
                "Microsoft Office", "Office14", "EXCEL.EXE");
Process.Start(fileName: exec, arguments: filePath);
```

**UPDATE**

You can obtain executable file by using Shell [AssocQueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773471(v=vs.85).aspx) function, which retrieves (amongst other properties) executable file associated with extension. Here's the method on C# which makes use of it:

```
[Flags]
public enum AssocF
{
    Init_NoRemapCLSID = 0x1,
    Init_ByExeName = 0x2,
    Open_ByExeName = 0x2,
    Init_DefaultToStar = 0x4,
    Init_DefaultToFolder = 0x8,
    NoUserSettings = 0x10,
    NoTruncate = 0x20,
    Verify = 0x40,
    RemapRunDll = 0x80,
    NoFixUps = 0x100,
    IgnoreBaseClass = 0x200
}

public enum AssocStr
{
    Command = 1,
    Executable,
    FriendlyDocName,
    FriendlyAppName,
    NoOpen,
    ShellNewValue,
    DDECommand,
    DDEIfExec,
    DDEApplication,
    DDETopic
}

public static class FileAssocHelper
{

    [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern uint AssocQueryString(AssocF flags, AssocStr str, string pszAssoc, string pszExtra, [Out] StringBuilder pszOut, [In][Out] ref uint pcchOut);

    public static string FileExtensionInfo(AssocStr assocStr, string doctype)
    {
        uint pcchOut = 0;
        AssocQueryString(AssocF.Verify, assocStr, doctype, null, null, ref pcchOut);
        StringBuilder pszOut = new StringBuilder((int)pcchOut);
        AssocQueryString(AssocF.Verify, assocStr, doctype, null, pszOut, ref pcchOut);
        return pszOut.ToString();
    }

}
```

Now we can retrieve executable file and open Excel file:

```
string filePath = @"c:\Temp\Results.xlsx";
string exec = FileAssocHelper.FileExtensionInfo(AssocStr.Executable, ".xlsx");
Process.Start(exec, filePath);
```

Comment: I salute you :D, took me a while to notice that my "Excel.EXE" is in "PrgoramFiles(x86)" so I've changed path `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles(x86)"),
                            "Microsoft Office", "Office14", "EXCEL.EXE");`

Comment: is there a way I could dynamically get "EXCEL.EXE" path?

Comment: @Yollo Glad it worked! I thought about dynamically finding EXCEL.EXE too, but for now can't tell something concrete. If I find a solution, I'll update an answer. :)

Comment: @Yollo I have found solution and will update an answer :)

Comment: thank you, stackoverflow literally schooled me :D , until your answer I didn't know why and where exactly this error occurs, only thing now is to make application portable xd.